# Using AWK to match the first expression, if it exists find next pattern, then insert

Tags: bash, macos, awk

I have this following snippet of file, dbScripts/product.js:

```
db.ShoppingCart.update(
    { 'identifier': 'COFFEE' },
    {
      'name': 'Coffee',
      'identifier': 'COFFEE',
      'category': 'Beverages',
      'type': [
        {
          'name': 'Rage',
          'identifier': 'COFFEE_RAGE',
          'desc':
            'Coffee by Rage'
        },
        {
            'name': 'Sleepy Owl',
            'identifier': 'COFFEE_SLEEPY_OWL',
            'desc':
              'Coffee by Sleepy Owl'
        }
      ]
    },
    { upsert: true }
);
```

I wish to first match {'identifier': 'COFFEE'}, if it exists, then and only then look for next subsequent pattern 'type': [

If both conditions are satisfied, the code should insert similar object for other coffee brand. But if the identifier entered is not coffee, it would create the entire structure for it. [The latter part has been accomplished].

```
FILE_PATH="./dbScripts/products.js"
# example, COFFEE
echo "Enter product"
read -r PRODUCT_NAME

DESCRIPTION="Coffee by Nescafe"
IDENTIFIER="COFFEE_NESCAFE"

FOUND=$(awk -v ITEM="{ \'identifier\': \'${PRODUCT_NAME}\' }" 'BEGIN {FOUND=0}/ITEM/{++FOUND} END {print FOUND+0}' "${FILE_PATH}")
        echo ${FOUND}
        if [ ${FOUND} -eq 1 ]; then
            SCRIPT_TEMPLATE="./AutomationUtil/object.tpl"
            local SCRIPT=$(eval "echo \"$(cat "${SCRIPT_TEMPLATE}")\"")
            awk -v text="${SCRIPT}" '1;/'type': | 'types': /{printf text}' "${FILE_PATH}" > "${FILE_PATH}_tmp" && mv "${FILE_PATH}_tmp" "${FILE_PATH}"
        fi
```

I am trying to use awk-variable FOUND as flag to check if the pattern is found or not. Proceed with next pattern if and only if FOUND=1

Object.tpl

```
{'name': '${PRODUCT_NAME}','identifier': '${PRODUCT_IDENTIFIER}','desc':'${DESCRIPTION}'},
```

So, if both subsequent patterns are found, the above template will be evaluated, and inserted. If not, the Entire Object Structure from dbScripts/product.js will created at the end of the file, example, user enters Tea instead of Coffee.

In the example below, user enters COFFEE as identifier, which matches our first pattern {'identifier': 'COFFEE'}, then it finds the line, 'type': [, and inserts the evaluated Object.tpl below it.

Expected OUTPUT:

```
    db.ShoppingCart.update(
            { 'identifier': 'COFFEE' },
            {
              'name': 'Coffee',
              'identifier': 'COFFEE',
              'category': 'Beverages',
              'type': [
                {
                  'name': 'Nescafe',
                  'identifier': 'COFFEE_NESCAFE',
                  'desc':
                    'Coffee by Nesafe'
                },
                {
                  'name': 'Rage',
                  'identifier': 'COFFEE_RAGE',
                  'desc':
                    'Coffee by Rage'
                },
                {
                    'name': 'Sleepy Owl',
                    'identifier': 'COFFEE_SLEEPY_OWL',
                    'desc':
                      'Coffee by Sleepy Owl'
                }
              ]
            },
            { upsert: true }
        );

  db.ShoppingCart.update(
            { 'identifier': 'NOODLES' },
            {
              'name': 'Noodles',
              'identifier': 'NOODLES',
              'category': 'Instant Food',
              'type': [
                {
                  'name': 'Ramen',
                  'identifier': 'NOODELS_RAMEN',
                  'desc':
                    'Noodles by Ramen'
                }
               ]
           }, {upsert: true}
         );
```

I came up with this theoretically, but can't seem to make it work. I always get FOUND=0.

I am sure, this code is very stupid, but any help is appreciated. Again, both patterns should be found in order to insert the object.

**NOTE: The formatting is being handled by prettier, so spacing should be ignored in case of new inserted text**

I do not wish to use SED because MacOS doesn't come with GNU-SED.

> awk version 20200816

Comment: Regarding `spacing can be ignored` - the job  becomes much harder if we have to solve the problem for all possible white space so saying spacing **can** be ignored is the wrong way to think about this. Either spacing **must** be ignored or spacing **can** be relied upon. Which is correct?

Comment: consider updating the question with enough details that we can reproduce the work in our own environments; in particular, provide values of all `$variables`, the contents of the *tpl file (to be inserted; if the file is 'large' then a smaller sample of the file would suffice), and the expected result; also, please update the question with theoutput from running `awk --version` on your system

Comment: @EdMorton noted! Prettier is formatting the code as per its configuration. So spacing should be ignored.

Comment: @markp-fuso I have tried to elaborate and add context, if it still lacks, please let me know

Comment: Again - does `spacing should be ignored` mean you need a script that doesn't rely on the spacing in your question (e.g. all of the input could be one single line) or not?

Comment: Okay, when you put it that way, "the spacing should be ignored", is specifically for the inserted code from object.tpl. So, ignore the indentation of inserted text. Script and pattern matching requires spacing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few issues with the current code but since the main question appears to be the wrong value assigned to the (`bash`) variable `FOUND`, I'll focus on just this issue ...

The main issue is the testing for the search pattern stored in the `awk` variable `ITEM`; one fix:

```
/ITEM/    {...}            # wrong
$0 ~ ITEM {...}            # fix
```

Incorporating this into OP's code, and plugging in some values for `INPUT` and `FILE_PATH` we get:

```
FOUND=$(awk -v ITEM="{ 'identifier' : '${INPUT}' }" '$0 ~ ITEM {++FOUND} END {print FOUND+0}' product.js)
$ echo "${FOUND}"
1
```

**NOTES:**

- escaped single quotes (defining the `awk` variable `ITEM`) are not needed
- `awk` variables have an initial value of 0 so no need for the `BEGIN{}` block
- this solution assumes the input has the same exact white space as defined in the `awk` variable `ITEM`

---

As for the rest of the question ...

- OP's 2nd `awk` script is looking for the strings `item:` or `items:` but no such string exists in the sample input, so I wouldn't expect anything to be 'inserted'; can't tell at this point if this is a typo/issue with the proposed `awk` code or faulty sample input
- the sample `Object.tpl` file shows a one-line element definition but the expected output shows this inserted as multiple lines; this result certainly won't be generated by the proposed (2nd) `awk` script so not sure if OP is also looking for an `awk` solution that inserst the line feeds or ... ??
- the entire `FOUND=$(awk ...); if ... awk ...;fi` block of code can probably be replaced with a single `awk` script
- OP's `awk` version (`awk version 20200816`) looks a bit odd so not sure what flavor/version of `awk` this really is or what limitations there may be with said version of `awk` (eg, does OP's `awk` version support `-i inplace` for allowing `awk` to perform an 'inplace' update of the `product.js` file?)

Comment: I understood what you have mentioned so far. I would like to add on though, product.js so far has only COFFEE. But let's say it had more products, so one entire db.ShoppingCart.update({'identifier': 'NOODLES'}) or more products. So if pattern matches identifier : COFFEE, i wish to add object.tpl to type within the COFFEE object.

Comment: sure, I understand that part (add the `*tpl` under the `COFFEE` section), but there are quite a few unknowns at this point that this feels more like writing an entire script as opposed to what SO is really for ... addressing specific technical issues with current code

Comment: I understand that, thank you nonetheless. I had an alternate option, if the "identifier: coffee" is matched, insert code at 6th line from that line. Can you guide me to solution of sorts. That would accomplish as well

Comment: 1. So it's my fault, "items" should be "type".
2. object.tpl is one liner to avoid \n syntax issue, but is later formatted with prettier which results in expected output.

Comment: Also, "How the bash variables in object.tpl is being resolved", i am using EVAL which substitutes bash variables with corresponding values.

Comment: `awk version 20200816` is a BSD awk so no `-i inplace`.